# JasperReport: how to repeat a field dynamically

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm very new to Jasper Report, and alter an existing jasper report to repeat a field dynamically. The current report is for a cashier receipt, which has in the footer a label signature, followed with a line, on which the client sign the receipt...

now, we mignt have more than a client (1 to 9). Thus, I need to repeat this line as many times as the number of users on the account. (the number of signers is set in field (Java bean) that is passed to the report.

Does anyone have a clue on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can use subreport or list component or table component

Comment: We might need to see some sample JRXML for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue and I wanted to share the solution with you. Actually, in my the reason why it didn't work is that I've put my fields (signatures and labeles) in the footer. It turns out that the footer is static. You specify its height once, and it remains the same. 
In contrary, the body can be adjusted dynamically dependins on the number of rows you displaying... unless you configure it otherwise.

I didn't try it, but I believe the header works the same way as the footer